# How to add number on button click in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, calculator

I am making this calculator and I want to add numbers on click. Should I add an event listener or is there an easier way? I want the number to go to the 'current' class.

```
<div class="calc-grid">
    <div class="output">
        <div class="prev">123</div>
        <div class="current">456</div>
    </div>
    <button class='span'>AC</button>
    <button>DEL</button>
    <button>÷</button>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>*</button>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <button>+</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
    <button>-</button>
    <button>.</button>
    <button>0</button>
    <button class='span'>=</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try Considering This One:

Probably Might Help You.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang = "en">  
<head>  
<title> JavaScript Calculator </title>  
  
<style>   
#clear{  
width: 270px;  
border: 3px solid gray;  
    border-radius: 3px;  
    padding: 20px;  
    background-color: blue;  
}  
  
.formstyle  
{  
width: 300px;  
height: 530px;  
margin: auto;  
border: 3px solid skyblue;  
border-radius: 5px;  
padding: 20px;  
}   
input  
{  
width: 20px;  
background-color: white;  
color: black;  
border: 3px solid gray;  
    border-radius: 5px;  
    padding: 26px;  
    margin: 5px;  
    font-size: 15px;  
}  
#calc{  
width: 250px;  
border: 5px solid black;  
    border-radius: 3px;  
    padding: 20px;  
    margin: auto;  
}  
  
</style>  
  
</head>  
<body>  
<div class= "formstyle">  
<form name = "form1">  
       
  <input id = "calc" type ="text" name = "answer"> <br> <br>  
  <input type = "button" value = "1" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '1' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "2" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '2' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "3" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '3' ">  
   <input type = "button" value = "+" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '+' ">  
  <br> <br>  
    
  <input type = "button" value = "4" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '4' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "5" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '5' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "6" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '6' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "-" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '-' ">  
  <br> <br>  
    
  <input type = "button" value = "7" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '7' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "8" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '8' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "9" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '9' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "*" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '*' ">  
  <br> <br>  
    
    
  <input type = "button" value = "/" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '/' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "0" onclick = "form1.answer.value += '0' ">  
    <input type = "button" value = "." onclick = "form1.answer.value += '.' ">  
  <input type = "button" value = "=" onclick = "form1.answer.value = eval(form1.answer.value) ">  
  <br>    
  <input type = "button" value = "Clear All" onclick = "form1.answer.value = ' ' " id= "clear" >  
  <br>   
    
</form>  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: onclick = "form1.answer.value += '1' " ...... consists of javascript

Comment: @Kiro does my solution helps you??

Comment: Yes, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use an onClick event to fire some JS code:

```
<button onClick="calculate(this)">1</button>
```

Also assign an id to the div you want to modify to make it simple to look up:

```
<div class="current" id="current">456</div>
```

Here's [an example that adds the number that you click on](https://codepen.io/gamma032steam/pen/RwgoQJY?editors=1111).